# Change Link Hover Color of Blog Titles - Avada

Tags: css, wordpress, hyperlink

At the blog archive page (https://ncmborz.com/blog/) blog titles change color on hover.

How can I change the link hover color?

Comment: Please update your post to include only your relevant code. This would include the HTML and any relevant CSS rules that you have written.

Comment: Has my answer helped you solve this in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following addition to whatever class your title has on it:

```css
.title-class:hover { color: red }
.link-class:hover { color: green }
```

```html
<h1 class="title-class">Blog Title</h1>
<a href="#" class="link-class">A link on the page</a>
```